# Making a recursive CTE like query, but for many records

Tags: sql-server, cte, recursive

I have a table with a hierarchy ( with a recursive parentID column), for one record, I know how to get the last parent record, with the following code :

```
declare @Id integer

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  a.[Id],
            a.[ParentId]
    FROM    [Area] a WITH (NOLOCK)
    where a.[Id] = @Id 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  a.[Id],
            a.[ParentId]
    FROM [Area] a WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN CTE cte ON cte.[ParentId] = a.[Id]
)

SELECT top 1 a.[Id]
FROM CTE a
WHERE a.ParentId is null
```

It works as long as I'm working with one id, here @Id.

But I can't find a way to do the same but for a list of Ids, without using cursors, as CTE seems to be OK only when y'oure working on one record.

Could someone point me at the right direction ?

Many thanks

Comment: And what do you mean with *"CTE seems to be OK ..."*? What happens if you amend the query to find the roots of many IDs, using `where a.[Id] IN (..list of IDs..)`, etc...?

Comment: Is this a single rooted hierarchy?  In other words, is there only one record with a null or empty ParentId?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the original table design is somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Area
(
    RowID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    GroupID  integer NOT NULL,
    ParentID integer NULL,
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT dbo.Area
    (RowID, GroupID, ParentID)
VALUES 
    (1, 1, NULL), -- Root
    (2, 1, 1),
    (3, 1, 2),
    (4, 2, NULL), -- Root
    (5, 2, 4),
    (6, 2, 5),
    (7, 2, 6);
```

The following recursive CTE query finds roots for the `RowID` list given in the anchor:

```
WITH R AS
(
    SELECT
        A.RowID,
        A.RowID AS OriginalRowID,
        A.ParentID
    FROM dbo.Area AS A
    WHERE
        A.RowID IN (3, 7)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        A.RowID,
        R.OriginalRowID,
        A.ParentID
    FROM dbo.Area AS A
    JOIN R
        ON R.ParentID = A.RowID
)
SELECT
    R.OriginalRowID,
    R.RowID
FROM R
WHERE
    R.ParentID IS NULL
ORDER BY
    R.OriginalRowID
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The output shows each supplied `RowID` and the root for that group:

[image: Output]

Comment: Yes. The query would work even if the hierarchy allowed for multiple parents of a node (it would find all root-ancestors of the selected/anchored nodes).